# How to prevent video from playing in background when a div is present?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm making a biking simulator where a user can pedal on a device, and their pedaling makes a video play. I want to add a pause screen which pauses the video while the screen is up.

Right now, I have a pause screen that when the div it's in appears, the video pauses, but if the user continues pedaling after the pause screen is up, the video will start to play again in the background.

This is what I'm using to display the pause screen and pause the video. The function gets called when the user pushes a button.

```
function togglePause() {
    var paused = document.getElementById("pauseScreen");
    if (paused.style.display == "none") {
        paused.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        paused.style.display = "none";
    }

    var vid = document.getElementById("video");
    vid.pause();
}
```

The pedaling device works like a bluetooth keyboard, where it sends a keypress events with each pedal rotation.

```
 $(document).keypress(function (event) {
        console.log(String.fromCharCode(event.which));

        if ('p'.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(event.which)) !== -1) {
            video.play();
```

I'd like to make it so as long as the div is displaying, the video cannot be played. Thanks!

Comment: How's the 'pedaling' triggered? Or in other words - can you post the code that starts playing the video?

Comment: @obscure, I added a section of the code that plays the video, let me know if that works

Comment: I don't get it. If you're commanding a div to show up, why don't you use the same function that calls the div to stop the video ? Same for play again when div disappears

Comment: I mean something like this https://pastebin.com/qPiv4uQG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly starting the video inside

```
if ('p'.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(event.which)) !== -1)
```

you can first check if the div's .display property is set to block and in case it is don't play the video.

```
if ('p'.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(event.which)) !== -1) {
  if (document.getElementById("pauseScreen").style.display != "block") {
    video.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hehe, true, this was not a big deal - glad I could help though!